# C# Selenium: Absence of polling interval makes a condition fail

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm using a custom condition that clicks a button until it's gone in a method that looks like that:

```
public bool UntilGone(By targetLocator)
    {
        Waits.Default.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(targetLocator));

        return Waits.Default.Until(d =>
        {
            try
            {
                _Action.Invoke(d.FindElement(targetLocator));
            }
            catch (StaleElementReferenceException) { }
            catch (NoSuchElementException) { }

            Thread.Sleep(200); // this one here

            return ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(targetLocator).Invoke(d);

        });
    }
```

For some reason until I added a `Thread.Sleep(200)` it failed a condition and threw a timeout exception.

Why's that? The element is still gone after click, it'd still try to click it, catch all the exceptions, fulfill the invisibility condition and exit the wait correctly. But it doesn't. A timeout exception suggests that it considers the element visible when it's clearly gone. What am I missing here? Why does `Thread.Sleep` make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

The method you've posted doesn't actually click the element. It just waits for it to be clickable. I'm not sure why a sleep would affect anything.

I would write that function differently. I would also suggest you give it a more descriptive name, I chose `ClickAndWaitUntilInvisible()`. The method below waits for the element to be clickable, clicks it, and then waits for the element to be invisible. It returns `true` if successful, `false` otherwise.

```
public bool ClickAndWaitUntilInvisible(By targetLocator)
{
    try
    {
        Waits.Default.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(targetLocator)).Click();
        return Waits.Default.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(targetLocator));
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's part of the library doing conditional actions made to interact with buttons that don't load watchers immediately that's why it looks like that. The click is actually wrapped into `_Action.Invoke(d.FindElement(targetLocator));` I think I should elaborate on that in the question, but I'm not sure how to avoid posting entire library here. Will think of something tomorrow.